# trouble with gemsets and dependecies of gems

Tags: ruby, rvm, bundler

I have 3 apps - app A is a container app. It uses a Gem called app B. App B has has a dependency on a third app, called App C.

All 3 apps are using the same version of ruby.

```
# inside ~/app_a: ruby-1.9.3-p327@mnhg
# $GEM_PATH: /Users/lfender/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@mnhg:/Users/lfender/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@global`

#app_a Gemfile
gem 'app_b', :path => '../app_b'

`bundle install` ---------------

#App A Gemfile.lock
PATH
remote: ../app_b
specs:
  app_b (0.0.8)
    dependency_1
    dependency_2
```

So now, depencies outlined in the .gemspec of app_b have been resolved by app_a, hooray.

```
#App B Gemspec
gem.add_dependency 'dependency_1'
gem.add_dependency 'dependency_2'
```

But what about the app_b/Gemfile, where i've outlined a 3rd local dependency?

```
# using ruby-1.9.3-p327@global

#App B Gemfile
gem 'app_c', :path => '../app_c'
```

If we look at the Gemfile.lock for App A above, you can see the depedency is not listed. How do I load and resolve a 2 level dependency such as this when I'm using a local app that uses a local gem that uses another local gem (also resolving its dependencies)?

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify all dependencies in the specification for the gem, using Gemfile for gems is not part of rubygems "standard", rubygems know only of `gem.add_dependency`, `gem.add_development_dependency` and `gem.add_runtime_dependency`, where `add_dependency` is an alias for: `add_runtime_dependency`.

Comment: yes, but i have not been able to find a way to use gem.add_dependency for local sources.

Comment: then you need to add the dependency to the top `Gemfile` used.